# Angular ui.grid paging vs. pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-grid

I am new to ui.grid and using the tutorial to get a grid with lots of data.
My version is 3.0.0.RC16 which I got from *bower install angular-ui-grid*

I would like to use paging but get errors.

There are 2 Tutorials regarding paging one called **Pagination** and one **Paging**:

- http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination
- http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/215_paging

Whats the difference between the two?
Module **'ui.grid.paging' does not exist** while 'ui.grid.pagination' does. What am I missing?

I want to use the paging example but always get errors
Do I need a special unstable release? how to install it with bower?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Meanwhile I manually downloaded the unstable version of ui-grid and indeed, **paging exists only in unstable.** I could not find explanations on the web why this is the case, so I assume that its not ready for prod. Nevertheless I would like to understand the difference to Pagination and if there is a bower package to install unstable versions.

**UPDATE**
meanwhile Paging was removed from the unstable versions. It seems the functionality was completely merged into pagination.
I had to change "paging" into "pagination" in controllers and views and everything seems to work (so far)

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/pull/2399

I was not the only one confused

Comment: As far as I know the 'pagination'-module was a first and new development of paging in ui-grid. A few weeks later, someone tried to reimplement the paging from the old grid-version nggrid in the new ui-grid and named it 'paging'. There are efforts to combine the two. See this issue on github: [link](http://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2106)

Comment: Thanks for that comment, you could post it as answer and I would accept it.

Comment: I just saw your bower-questions and thought that my comment is not an answer at all.

Comment: for BOWER I have no solution, there is no bower package for the unstable version. But you can always tweak the bower files manually and force it to reference the unstable version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not using bower so I cannot help you with this one.

But I can tell you a few words to the difference of 'paging' and 'pagination' in ui-grid:

As far as I know the 'pagination'-module was a first and new development of paging in ui-grid. A few weeks later, someone tried to reimplement the paging from the old grid-version nggrid in the new ui-grid and named it 'paging'.

There are efforts to combine the two. See this issue on github:

http://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2106

Facing rapid changes in ui-grid, github seems to be the best place to get answers to problems with ui-grid. The tutorial is most of the time not up to date.
But the active developers react very fast on incoming issues on github.